# laravel Insert big integer into mysql resulted wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In laravel, I tested this:

```
Record::create(['data' => 2147483648]);exit;
```

When I check mysql table, `data` column value is `-2147483648`, but `data` column type is `bigint(20)`.

My php version is 7.1, mysql version is 5.6, is there any problem with my environment ?

Comment: Is PHP 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: @RiggsFolly 64bit,  I think the problem may be the php mysql driver

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: try `Record::create(['data' => '2147483648'])`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir linux